# .htaccess no-html redirection vs directory name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I plan on implementing this .htaccess code (thanks anubhava) into my website:

```
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Basically it will change URL from "www.mydomain.com/this-page.html" into "www.mydomain.com/this-page" - it does that very well.

However, I have encountered an issue - let's say that one of my pages is "treatments.html".

URL adress will look like this "mydomain.com/treatments" and that's fine. But I want also to make a directory called "treatments" and include the list of available treatments in that folder, it would look like this

```
"mydomain.com/treatments/treatment-one"
"mydomain.com/treatments/treatment-two"
"mydomain.com/treatments/treatment-three"
```

and so on...

**THE ISSUE IS:**
When I try to access the file "treatments.html" browser confuses it with the directory and server sends message [403]Forbidden.

Any ideas for solution?

Comment: Do you have `/treatments/treatment-one.html` file also?

Comment: yes, in "treatments" directory there will be multiple .html files

Answer (score 0):

Ok change your last rule to:

```
DirectorySlash On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

rewritecond %{http_host} !^mydomain\.com$ [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: My code looks like this now:                                  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]                                    It still does not work properly (still [403]forbidden)

Comment: Still mydomain.com/treatments = [403] forbidden; it goes to directory, not the html file

Comment: But your URL should be `/treatments/treatment-one` for href.

Comment: Yes there is mydomain.com/treatments/treatment-one.html but mydomain.com/treatments.html is also there - it is the list of treatments on that page, then u choose one that is in the directory called "treatments" too, is it possible to do this?

Comment: I believe my most recent update will take care of this situation. Try it and let me know.

Comment: I am sorry to say but it still does not work. Perhaps I shuould forget about adding treatments.html and just create index.html in /treatments directory?

Comment: Exact same rule is working for me on my localhost. You may have some conflicting rule. Provide your full .htaccess in your question. Do you have some other .htaccess also?

Comment: My question was updated. It is the only .htaccess file I use on that server.

Comment: see your complete .htaccess in y answer.

Comment: Sorry for answering with such a long delay! I tried implementing the code you provided. Now there is no "[403] Forbidden" message, instead the user is directed into following address: "mydomain.com/treatments/" (yes,with "/" at the end of address). It reads the treatments.html file, therefore the html structure is there but links are not working (no css file connected, internal links do not work). My css files are in mydomain.com/styles.css directory.

Comment: After implementing your code, page is pointing into mydomain.com/treatments/styles.css - like the file treatments.html was in "treatments" directory (it is not, it is in root folder).

Comment: see updated code and use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`